# How to translate the German word “kraftbetätigt”?

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, allemand

I am trying for find a suitable translation for the German word *kraftbetätigt*.  It is some kind of power-assisted action using a motorised or hydraulic power source. For example, *kraftbetätigte Schutzschieber*.

One suggestion has been *assisté* or *asservi* with *hydrauliquement* or *électriquement* added as a supplement if the power type is known.

We are looking for a succinct term to use for our terminology.
Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 5):

*Assisté* or *motorisé* seems better than *asservi* (which I'd use when tracking is in place).

Answer (score 3):

In this case, I think it would be better described as *actionné à distance*.

In standard technical jargon, the power source is however specified as follows:

> à commande hydraulique (pneumatique, électrique, etc.).

Linguee sometimes reports such occurrences, e.g [here](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-allemand/search?source=auto&query=Schutzschieber) and [here](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-allemand/search?source=auto&query=kraftbet%E4tigte).

Comment: I can imagine very easily something "à commande électrique" with an hydraulic power source.  I don't know enough of German to state how this influence the qualitiy of your suggestion.

Comment: @Unf: I think “actionner” would be quite a good match for “betätigen” (hopefully, the wiktionary can confirm…).

Answer (score 2):

I think of *actionné par une source d'énergie extérieure*.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the translation could also bring up the general idea of "a running state electrical device".

> Der Schutzschieber bleibt kraftbetätigt, die Spritzeinheit horizontal.
>
> The safety gate remains poweractivated, the injection unit horizontal.

To me, this word means a general idea of "something motorized or running with a mecanical force"

Comment: I've seen this translation at Linguee and I can't really make much sense of it. Do you have a (short) French translation for 'power-activated' ?

Comment: I'd say "allumé" or "en fonctionnement" ...

Comment: Not sure that is correct. Power-activated means activated using power - as opposed to activated by hand. e.g. power-steering